# Spring data jpa with hibernate can't find column in sequence

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, sequence

So I'm using PostgreSQL database in my Spring MVC project and I created table with sequence for primary key generating. And I have a problem with hibernate getting next value for inserting rows. This is how my entity looks like:

```
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "employee_s")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "employee_s", sequenceName = "employee_s", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "id_pk")
private Long id;
```

And Im getting error while inserting data like this:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: Column "next_val" does not exist
```

Well this column does not exist in sequence but why even hibernate is looking for this column?

But when I changed generation stragety it worked:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id_pk")
private Long id;
```

How can I fix it to use sequence stragety or should I just stick to IDENTITY, because it works? PostgreSQL uses strategies so I wanted to try them out